# Why is the react app not displaying image

Tags: html, css, reactjs, image, mern

I am making a react website and on the single product page, my image is not displayed perfectly. I have tried changing the react code and the CSS code but nothing is working

**Here is my react file**

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import Carousel from "react-material-ui-carousel";
import "./ProductDetails.css";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { getProductDetails } from '../../actions/productAction';
import ReactStars from 'react-rating-stars-component';

const ProductDetails = ({}) => {
    const { id } = useParams();
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const { product, loading, error } = useSelector(
        (state)=>state.productDetails
    );
    
    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(getProductDetails(id));
    }, [dispatch, id])
    
    const options = {
        edit: false,
        color: "rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.1)",
        activeColor: "tomato",
        size: window.innerWidth < 600 ? 20 : 25,
        value: product.ratings,
        isHalf: true
    };

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <div className="ProductDetails">
                <div>
                    <Carousel>
                        {product.images &&
                        product.images.map((item, i) => (
                            <img
                            className="CarouselImage"
                            key={item.url}
                            src={item.url}
                            alt={`${i} Slide`}
                        />
                        ))}
                    </Carousel>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <div className="detailsBlock-1">
                        <h2>{product.name}</h2>
                        {/* <p>Product # {product._id}</p> */}
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </Fragment>
    );
};

export default ProductDetails;
```

**Here is my CSS code**

```
.ProductDetails {
    background-color: rgb(214, 214, 214);
    width: 100vw;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 6vmax;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
}
```

[Here is the image that is displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvIoS.png)

I tried changing my CSS and the code in the react file but nothing is working. What should I do so that my page looks like this

[Desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rs3RT.png)

Comment: try to put console.log(item.url) and see the url format recieved

Comment: First, open the network tab in the developer tools to check for any image requests.
If there is successful network request, check for heigt and width of the image  element.

Comment: I tried both the ways console logging as well checking the network tab
Everything is working perfectly. Still the image is not displayed in the browser

Answer (score 0):

Give height and width to the image by class name or inline style:

In your CSS file replace this.

```
.CarouselImage {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```